# Image editing in resources of visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, image, png

I want to be able to edit an image (png file) from the resources folder of one of my projects in VS2008. But the resource editor in VS will only allow me to zoom in and out. As the images are 32 bit, VS also will not allow me to use the image editor toolbar to change this. I would like to know if anyone knows how i can edit the image via VS or an associated plugin that is safe to use with source control?!
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the VS resource editor supports editing PNG files (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471265/importing-png-files-in-visual-studio-c-resource-editor)).

I'm not sure what you mean by "safe to use with source control" -- any image editor should fit the bill.  Check out the file, locking it if necessary, then edit it with your favorite image editor, such as [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org).  When you're done, check in.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure if VS has any built in image editing applications that meet your needs. However, for editing our image resources I've set it up so that the default application launched when selecting certain filetypes is Photoshop (or a different editor depending on the change required).

Changing the default opened program for a filetype can be done using the following steps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy2sthf1.aspx

As for source control safety, I use AccuRev with the AccuBridge plug in for VS. So anytime any of the files under source control are modified it is noted as such. Then these files can be committed as required either through VS AccuBridge plug in or through the regular source control client.